# building a select statement in oracle using values stored in variables

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Is there a way to build a select statement in oracle using values stored in variables?
For example can you do this:

```
 declare 
 tbl_var varchar2(10) := "map_set";

begin
select count(*) from tbl_var;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, using execute immediate:

```
declare 
 tbl_var varchar2(10) := 'map_set';
 result number;

begin
execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||tbl_var into result; --save result into variable
dbms_output.put_line('Total rows:'||result); --print result
end;
```

Second way, you can create a function that receives table name as parameter and return the count:

```
create function get_count(tbl_var varchar2) return number is 

 result number;

begin
execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||tbl_var into result;
return result;
end;
```

After create the function you can query it like this:

```
select get_count('map_set') from dual;
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong, but I don't get anything in the Data Grid in Toad.

But when I run:
    select count(*) from map_set;

I get a count value returned.

Comment: you don't see anything because this is plsql code, datagrid is for sql. If you want to see results, you must use `dbms_output.put_line` and check `DBMS Output` in toad. Check edit

Comment: Check the second way, this will show result in the grid

Comment: Ok great! this certainly works ;)

I have a follow up question, don't know if I should open a separate thread for it.

Comment: Will 'execute immediate' work for functions as well, I tried it but get an invalid sql statement.

Comment: i moved the count statement inside a function called 'test_func' and then tried the following code:

Comment: declare
    my_func varchar2(200) := 'test_func';
    result number;

    begin 
    execute immediate 'select' || my_func || 'from dual' into result;
    dbms_output.put_line('My function output:' || result);
    end;

Comment: check that you are building the select statement wrong, you are missing spaces between select and the name of the function, and the space before the `from`. So your execute immediate should be like: `execute immediate 'select ' || my_func || ' from dual' into result;`